# Make extra parameters passed in URL as optional

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have this URL `path('user/delete/<int:pk>/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_user'),`

to delete a selected user via passing the `pk` of the user to be accessed by the `DeleteView` . However, I want to delete multiple users by using a form with checkboxes. For that, I have used a separate view.

my question is that is there any way that I can make this `<int:pk>` as optional parameter so that I can use the same view for POST as well as GET requests. Just in case I want to use the POST method for the same URL. Can this be done? Someone said it can be done optional in Ruby on Rails. Is there any way to do this here in Django?

Comment: I have permission give to superuser only.  I am actually trying to create a copy of Admin interface provided by Django.

Comment: this is not relevant. The HTTP standard specifies that a GET is used to *retrieve* information, not *alter* information: "*The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.*" (src: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me if I can make the ```<int:pk>``` argument as optional? Is there any way? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two paths, one with the primary key, and another one *without* the primary key:

```
path('user/delete/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_user'),
path('user/delete/<int:pk>/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_user_id'),
```

We thus have two views here: `'delete_user'` that takes no `pk`, and `'delete_user_id'` that takes a primary key.  Both direct to the same `UserDeleteView`.

You can inject a value for the missing parameter, by using the `kwargs=` parameter:

```
path('user/delete/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_user', kwargs={'pk': None}),
path('user/delete/<int:pk>/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_user_id'),
```

That being said, using GET requests are supposed to have no side effects. That is how the [HTTP protocol [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) is designed:

> The GET method **requests a representation** of the specified resource. Requests using GET should **only retrieve data and should have no other effect**. (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.) The W3C has published guidance principles on this distinction, saying, "Web application design should be informed by the above principles, but also by the relevant limitations.".

The W3 organization has also [guidelines when to use GET or POST](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist):

> Use GET if:
>
> - The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a **safe operation such as a query, read operation**, or lookup).
>
> Use POST if:
>
> - The interaction is more like an order, or
> - The interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g., a subscription to a service), or
> - The user be held accountable for the results of the interaction.

If you want to delete items, you usually make a DELETE or a POST request. Django for example will protect such requests with a CSRF token, to prevent [cross-site request forgery [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

I therefore strongly recommend that you only allow POST/DELETE requests for these views, of course with extra checks to see if the user is authorized to make the changes.

Comment: how can you delete multiple instances of an object using delete view?

Comment: @Deshwal: how did you *implement* the `UserDeleteView`?

Comment: class UserDeleteView(DeleteView): 
     success_url= reverse_lazy('admin:user_list') 
    model = User

Comment: @Deshwal: Django's builtin delete view has no functionality to delete "in bulk", furthermore the default implementation only takes URL parameters.

Comment: It deletes a single object using the get method. But how  can I delete multiple objects at once via Post method?

Comment: @Deshwal: it does not: it deletes a *single* object through a POST request: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/ the GET will render a confirmation dialog that will then perform a POST request. The `DeleteView` is *not* designed to do deletes in bulk. You will need to "roll your own".

Comment: Generic detail view UserDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf. This is the error that keeps coming

Comment: @Deshwal: of course, because a `DeleteView` is not implemented to delete objects in *bulk*. You will need to implement a "`BulkDeleteView`" yourself for that.